# regex string correct but not working

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a regex expression which is

```
function checkNum(form) {
    var regex = "/^\d+/";
    if (!form.value.match(regex)) {
        alert('Please Enter value again');
        form.value = "";
    }
}
```

but it is not working.

I have entered this regex expression /^\d+$/ in this website http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascriptexample.html but it doesnt seem to work too in this website. I am pretty sure this expression is correct

Comment: what are you trying to match .. what are you geting ...?

Comment: The regex will match a string that starts with at least 1 digit. Is that what you meant for the regex to do? And did you mean to include it quotes? And what is `form` that you're passing?

Comment: maybe you need to get rid of your `"`, so declaring the regex by `var regex = /^\d+/` ... those `/` actually indicate regex in javascript and do not need to be enclosed by quotation marks.
if thats not the solution, could you specify what the regex should do?

Comment: @Chips_100 that's right, he's just doing a match with a string, not a regex. Therefore the results are unexpected.

Comment: Check out the [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex literal is `/^\d+/` *without* quotes.

```
function checkNum(form) {
    var regex = /^\d+$/; //Pure digits from start to end
    if (!form.value.match(regex)) {
        alert('Please Enter value again');
        form.value = "";
    }
}
```

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/KvuaM/

---

If you pass the *string* `"/^\d+/"` to `.match()` you will get a regex equivalent of `/\/^d+\//` because of the implicit conversion and invalid `"\d"` escape.

```
new RegExp("/^\d+/").source
//"/^d+/"
```

Comment: @thg435 On another note, why does `/\/^d+\//.source` show the escapes?  I cannot write `//^d+//` either. Also gives different result in Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: It shows escapes because, well, escapes are there. You cannot have an unescaped `/` in a regexp. `//..//` is parsed as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You have slashes in the string, which are interpreted as literals.
Either remove them from the string, or use them in order to create a regular expression
"^\d+"
or
/^\d+/